# How do I display external API search results in a table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, external

I am a final year student and am creating a food log web application for my major project.  I have created a search function that allows me to search and display external API results, but now I wish to display them in a table, can anyone help please?
I would prefer if it would be a table that can be filtered, eg, the columns ordered ascending/descending?

Thanks

```
function get foodItem(userInput) {
    var storedSearchItem;
    $('.resultContainer').html('');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        url: 'https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/'+userInput+'?'+
        'fields=item_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_name%2Cnf_calories%2Cnf_total_fat&appId=325062a4&appKey=bf1a30b2066602dc6f33db888cd53bd3',
        success: function(d) {
            storedSearchItem = d.hits;
        }
    });

storedSearchItem.map(function(item) {
        var x = item.fields
        $('.resultContainer').append(
            '<div class="itemBar">'+
                '<h2>' + x.item_name + '<h2>' +
                '<h3>Calories: ' + x.nf_calories + '<h3>' +
                '<h3>Serving Size: ' + x.nf_serving_size_qty + ' ' + x.nf_serving_size_unit +'<h3>' +
                '<h3>Total Fat: ' + x.nf_total_fat + '<h3>' +
            '</div>'
            );
    });
}//ends get result function

function searchValue() {
    var formVal = document.getElementById('itemSearch').value; //value from search bar
    getFoodItem(formVal);
}

$('#searchForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});`
```

Comment: Don't build HTML by concatenating strings like that. It's hard to read and insecure.

Comment: You should move your code to the success function , Jquery is buggy and slow if you could use something else that will be good

Comment: put the storedSearchItem inside ajax success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append your table in the success function

your code will look like something like this

```
 success: function(d) {
            storedSearchItem = d.hits;
storedSearchItem.map(function(item) {
        var x = item.fields
        $('.resultContainer').append(
            '<div class="itemBar">'+
                '<h2>' + x.item_name + '<h2>' +
                '<h3>Calories: ' + x.nf_calories + '<h3>' +
                '<h3>Serving Size: ' + x.nf_serving_size_qty + ' ' + x.nf_serving_size_unit +'<h3>' +
                '<h3>Total Fat: ' + x.nf_total_fat + '<h3>' +
            '</div>'
            );
    });
        }
```